# What's a good iPhone app for playing MP3 music?

Tags: iphone, software-recommendation, ios-appstore, music, mp3

I have an extensive collection of [video game music](http://www.ocremix.org) that I like to keep completely separate from my 'regular' music (which I use iTunes to sync w/ my iPhone and the stock Music.app to play).

I'm looking for a good app that will let me import this separate collection of MP3s into the app and then play them. Most importantly, it must *NOT* pull in music from the stock music.app, as I want to keep these two separate!

- I don't want a digital locker to sign up for and stream from (Amazon, etc)
- ID3 tag meta-data support is a must, preferably w/ embedded album art
- Needs to list songs by Album/Artist/Song Title, not just filename
- Playlist is nice to have but not a must
- I don't care how it looks as long as it's not total garbage
- I don't care about downloading from the internet; I've already got the songs I need

Are there any apps out there that can do this? I've had no luck searching Google as all I find are questionable MP3 Downloaders, Youtube rippers, streamers, or authoring/remixing tools. :/

Thanks for any input you guys have.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: What is the reason that you do *not* want to use iTunes for this?

Comment: I love using siri to say "Shuffle music" and it plays all my 'normal' music randomly. However I do not want to mix in my video game music w/ the normal music. I want them as two distinct collections. Likewise I don't want them getting mixed in with other areas that read the standard music library.

Comment: Can't you just use play lists to separate the libraries?

Comment: No, because when I tell siri to shuffle music, it'll shuffle all music...

Comment: You can also do something like "Shuffle my roadtrip playlist" or "Play album-such-and-such shuffled".

Comment: Why not use playlists for both, and then tell Siri to shuffle the specific playlist instead of shuffle all music?

Comment: patrix: I had no idea I could separate them this way. I ended up using a Smart Playlist where Genre != "Game" for my regular music, and Game for the other one. Works beautifully! If you'd like to post your suggestion in the form of an answer, I will accept it, if you care about that sort of thing. Thanks!

Comment: Did you also see RKO? http://remix.kwed.org/

Comment: When I want to make sure iTunes doesn't play certain tracks when it shuffles I just uncheck those tracks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a few years later, and there are finally a couple of apps available that do this. Most don't work, but [foobar2000](https://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/foobar2000/id1072807669) seems to do the job.

At the time of this writing it does not support the Files app but it does at least have its own FTP server, making it fairly easy to transfer files regardless of your OS. (No iTunes required!)

Answer (score 4):

VLC is very popular on any device or computer. The iOS Version has a really nice design (iOS 7 like) and supports any kind of transfer (Wifi, Networkstream, ...).

More information can be found here: http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-ios.html

Answer (score 1):

I personally use [Capriccio](https://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/capriccio-ultimate-music-player/id434828497?mt=8), which has a free with ads version and paid version. The plus of this player is that it runs both iPhone standards formats and all the other (including FLAC) so you can basically throw it everything without converting and you have no problem.

Comment: This one is okay, but it does not support browsing by Artist/Album/etc. It's just a list of filenames ending in .mp3 :/

Answer (score 1):

VLC player has Wifi upload + dropbox integration - although both did not work for me - VLC cant detect mp3 even after i Wifi-upload them.

Use latest verison of DropBox - it automatically plays mp3 inside..
https://www.dropbox.com/help/80/en