# I copied MP3 file to Iphone but Music app does not see it

Tags: ios, music

I am not everyday user of iphone. So I connected iphone 4 with ios 7 to my Ubuntu 14.04 machine, Nautilus opened and I copied mp3 files so Downloads folder.

Then I disconnected the phone and opened Music app, but it was empty.

Where should I copy mp3 files so Music can see them?

Can Music app see WAV files as well?

Comment: See http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/92087/whats-a-good-iphone-app-for-playing-mp3-music?rq=1 for a similar problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately Apple has 'decreed' that none shall use an iPhone/iPod without the concurrent use of iTunes to manage the device.

Yeah this is what other people said but with the addition that you can't really. Not without a fair amount of hacking around in the iPhone. The iPhone's filesystem is not exposed to general usage and not designed to be used with Linux (EG no iTunes for Linux). While there **might** be a way (and a place) to copy your audio files (yes the iPhone plays generic MP3 and WAV files) to your iPhone manually, it is generally not supported.

What you may want to do is see if there is an iTunes equivalent application for Linux that will let you sync music/podcasts/etc. If you do please post that here, it might be helpful to others.

Comment: I don't think there is. I tried in the past and everyone directed me to use iTunes via Windows on vmware. The only way to access usb ports is this way.

Comment: If you can read the filesystem, and I mean **all** of it. You may be able to locate where the songs are. Maybe search for a song that is already there(?) And place new ones there. But there is likely metadata that needs to be updated too, usually done with iTunes...

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can only use iTunes to transfer media into the iOS Music app.

In your case you can either run iTunes in a Windows VM or use another app to play music with (VLC comes to mind, there might be others).

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to copy mp3's to any iphone using itunes. Follow the steps -

1. Connect your device to computer
2. Open itunes and select your connected device
3. if asked for update, cancel it - no need to upgrade (upgrade will out-date your phone and you have to go for new one)
4. Scroll to options section and select "Sync only checked songs and videos", "Convert higher bit rate songs to 128kbps (select anything you want) AAC" & "Manually manage music and videos"
5. Apply the changes
6. Drag and drop your music/videos to music or existing playlist or create new.
7. Then press sync - all grayed list of songs will now be copied to your phone/ipod.
8. Eject your phone after all songs are synced.
9. Check them out in "Music/My music"

Happy hearing...

Answer (score 0):

You can still open such files but with third party applications not directly through the music app.

Such as file manegment applications.
 *FileHub* is an example...

Comment: Some examples of such apps would be helpful here.