# How do I play an mp3 on my iPad?

Tags: itunes, ipad, music, mp3

I'm not trained on iOS and my iPad 6th Gen is the only Apple product I own.

iOS version is 13.3.
I have downloaded the app called, "Music"
I have downloaded Readdle Documents.

Using Documents, I have downloaded an mp3 file.  Now I'm not sure how to get the Music app to "see" it.
It seems like I need to add it to "Music's" Library, but cannot find the option to do so.

One solution I recall but can’t cite said to install an app called "iTunes", but I could not find it in the app store.  I did find "iTunes Store" but that seems to only be a way to purchase content.

- I am looking to use the content I already own.
- I have no access to a desktop system that I can install software on, so any external or 3rd party tools are not accessible.
- I don’t know how I’ll bulk load mp3 as well since I lack a computer and readdle won’t let me manage playlists.

Can someone get me started to how to play MP3?

Comment: It’s totally cool to not know how to do things. I hope the edit makes it clear what sort of overall advice you seek. The big stumbling block is you want things in files, not sandboxed app storage.

Comment: You comment on "sandboxed app storage" lead me on a search to find this comment, https://stackoverflow.com/a/12056039/3266961  which indicates that it is impossible to play an mp3 file without some external tool that puts the mp3 in the music app.  I guess coming from a linux, android, palmos, unix, and windows world, I find this odd behavior, and extremely limiting in functionality.  Thanks for the help

Comment: There’s a [nice answer here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/378288/5472). mp3 are playable out of the box on iOS - no need for an App, so get them in the files app any way you please. Worst case you add an app of your choice and point it to the files you loaded in the files app. @ me if you want more help on this or have a follow on question. I think you have some great options - just not sure what point you’re stuck on TBH.

Comment: Here? Where is Here @bmike I'm still interested in figuring this out.

Comment: I like ankii’s answer. And that it points to two other good related questions.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't have a Mac, I suggest you start looking into third party music players like VLC, "Cloud Music Player - Listener" by Jhon Belle, "Boom: Music Player and Equalizer" by Global Delight Technologies Pvt. Ltd, Google Play music, "Vox- MP3 & FLAC music player" by Coppertino Inc. etc.

- [What's a good iPhone app for playing MP3 music?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/92087/whats-a-good-iphone-app-for-playing-mp3-music)

If a Mac can be used:

- [How to add podcasts manually to the new Podcasts.app on macOS Catalina](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/366075/how-to-add-podcasts-manually-to-the-new-podcasts-app-on-macos-catalina)
- > On your Mac, you can download audiobooks from Audible.com, then drag and drop them into Apple Books.

  https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT208929#booklets

Comment: I’ve edited the question to remove all the fluff about not knowing how to search. You might need to rework this based on OP edits. We can assume no one is searching well if they don’t show specific references so no need to worry about that @allankll